# Capturing reads, writes, and CPU in SQL Server replay Trace results

Tags: sql-server, testing, replay

I'm trying to guide devs to use replay traces to A/B test code optimizations and their correlating database impact. In my sample I use the replay Trace template and while I can include CPU, reads, writes in the capture Trace, the only way I can gather these metrics in the replay results is running a second Trace to intercept that traffic.

Is there a way to modify the replay result template to include these fields? I'd think you'd be able to since you can get results, execution times, etc.

-Edit - Target is a 2014 instance, but also tried a 2016 instance.  I've tried 2014, 2016, and 2018 SSMS JIC there were different profiler functionalities.  Haven't found much in regards to documentation.

Comment: @Nickolas; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools available for performance tuning.
For example, Entity Framework Profiler (commercial tool sold on a subscription basis - which limits availability) could satisfy any developer (that using EF as ORM) in tracing and tuning.

[image: Entity Framework Profiler Screenshot]

In other hands, SQL Server profiler is an advance tool to trace your work.

So, I can help if you specify what ORM is using.

Comment: EF aside, this answer would be improved by mentioning that this is a commercial tool sold on a subscription basis (which limits availability), and also whether or not it offers A/B testing in the form of replay functionality. SQL Server's own replay traces do.

Comment: @JeroenMostert; Thanks.

Comment: This is more allowing a tech lead to provide metrics on proposing an optimization.  They'd currently use VS diagnostics to provide their materialization level improvements (yes EF, but not always), then ideally metrics from some replay trace trials where they'll be able to flush plan cache, restore to snapshot, replay a scenario with their staged data, possibly add some index coverage during the process, provide stats on improved reads/writes/cpu (more than just execution times/overall trace completion time).

Comment: These metric can be gathered with a second profiler trace, but it's a bit of a clunky situation to provide as a reusable process where I'm trying to make this fast/effective, so I wanted to see if anyone knew of something I was missing.